# Terminate Linked List input

Tags: c++

[Image displays the input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdr95.png)
I would like to know how to terminate the input for a linked list. 
like usually i would ask user to enter -1 when he is done giving input. but if there is undefined number of input terms like
1 4 5 3 2 2 4 5 already present in console.
How will i program linked list to accept this 8 values and proceed there after.
I am using c++

I was trying to solve this problem...
https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/programming-interview-questions/challenges/m-th-to-last-element

This is what I've done to accept input (conventional way)

```
struct node * createLL(struct node * start)
{
    struct node * new_node;
    int inp=0;

    while(inp!=-1)
    {
        cin>>inp;
        new_node = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node *));
        new_node->data = inp;

        if(start == NULL)
        {
            new_node->next = NULL;
            start = new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            struct node * ptr;
            ptr = start;
            while(ptr->next!=NULL)
            {
                ptr=ptr->next;
            }
            ptr->next = new_node;
            new_node->next = NULL;
        }
    }
    return start;

}
```

Comment: You should show what you have tried and ask for help with a specific problem of your approach.

Comment: All the numbers are on one single line separated by space. Create a node for each of the number. This line might end (i.e last character on line) with `\n` or last digit of last number.

Comment: And your link also not working